# Issue with rawQuery() in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to execute a query to retrieve some data from the table.

Below is my query:

```
cursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myNumber="+"'myCustomNumber'", null);
```

where myNumber is type of 'TEXT'

But every time I am getting `cursor.getCount() = 0;`

It seems there's a mistake in my query.

Please let me know the correct way of writing above query.

Comment: you are literally searching for `myNumber='myCustomNumber'`. unless `myCustomNumber` is actually the value you are looking for, this looks like a typo to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be use below code :

cursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myNumber='"+myCustomNumber+"'", null);

i hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

In your query the parameter passed as myNumber has become a text due the double quotes around it.

Change it to,

```
cursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myNumber = ' " + myCustomNumber + "'", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

String phoneNo = "0000000000";

String query = "Select * from  where  mynumber = '" +phoneNo+ "'";

cursor = myDB.rawQuery(query,null);

Answer (score 0):

you can execute that query i.e.

```
rawQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myNumber= = ? ", new String[] {"myCustomNumber"});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the query that you have used, the number has not been passed in quotes.

```
cursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myNumber="+"'myCustomNumber'", null);
```

That query would mean `myNumber= myCustomNumber` **literally**, and not a variable value.

You need to add the quotes before and after your myCustomNumber like:

```
cursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myNumber="+"'"+myCustomNumber+"'", null);
```